# Spring Web Reactive client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use the Spring Reactive WebClient to upload a file to a spring controller. The controller is really simple and looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(
        @RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile multipartFile,
        @RequestParam Map<String, Object> entityRequest
        ) {
    entityRequest.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println(multipartFile);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

When I use this controller with cURL everything works fine

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/upload -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' -F fileName=test.txt -F randomKey=randomValue -F multipartFile=@document.pdf
```

The multipartFile goes to the correct parameter and the other parameters go in to the Map.

When I try to do the same from the WebClient I get stuck. My code looks like this:

```
    WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.set("multipartFile", new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/my/document.pdf"))));
    map.set("fileName", "test.txt");
    map.set("randomKey", "randomValue");
    String result = client.post()
            .uri("/upload")
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .syncBody(map)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class))
            .flux()
            .blockFirst();
    System.out.println("RESULT: " + result);
```

This results in an 400-error

```
{
  "timestamp":1510228507230,
  "status":400,
  "error":"Bad Request",
  "message":"Required request part 'multipartFile' is not present",
  "path":"/upload"
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try using @RequestPart for MultipartFile multipartFile

Comment: I did that already, but that doesn't make a difference. I found another solution and i will post it.

Answer (score 8):

So i found a solution myself. Turns out that Spring really needs the Content-Disposition header to include a filename for a upload to be serialized to a MultipartFile in the Controller.

To do this i had to create a subclass of ByteArrayResource that supports setting the filename

```
public class MultiPartResource extends ByteArrayResource {

  private String filename;

  public MultiPartResource(byte[] byteArray) {
    super(byteArray);
  }

  public MultiPartResource(byte[] byteArray, String filename) {
    super(byteArray);
    this.filename = filename;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
  }

  public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
  }
}
```

Which can then be used in the client with this code

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();

MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

map.set("fileName", "test.txt");
map.set("randomKey", "randomValue");
ByteArrayResource resource = new MultiPartResource(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/my/document.pdf")), "document.pdf");

String result = client.post()
        .uri("/upload")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(map))
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class))
        .flux()
        .blockFirst();
System.out.println("RESULT: " + result);
```

Comment: Dont forget the call to `map.set("multipartFile", resource)`

Comment: Must be simpler according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23372#issuecomment-516793172

Comment: This is definitely should be marked as a solution. The official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body doesn't mention this. Also, a simple way mentioned by aholub7x works great.

Answer (score 3):

You need include a filename to file part to upload success, in combination with `asyncPart()` to avoid buffering all file content, then you can write the code like this:

```java
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();

Mono<String> result = client.post()
        .uri("/upload")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body((outputMessage, context) ->
                Mono.defer(() -> {
                    MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();

                    Flux<DataBuffer> data = DataBufferUtils.read(
                            Paths.get("/tmp/file.csv"), outputMessage.bufferFactory(), 4096);

                    bodyBuilder.asyncPart("file", data, DataBuffer.class)
                            .filename("filename.csv");

                    return BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(bodyBuilder.build())
                            .insert(outputMessage, context);
                }))
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class));

System.out.println("RESULT: " + result.block());
```

Answer (score 3):

Easier way to provide the Content-Disposition

```
MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
String header = String.format("form-data; name=%s; filename=%s", "paramName", "fileName.pdf");
builder.part("paramName", new ByteArrayResource(<file in byte array>)).header("Content-Disposition", header);

// in the request use
webClient.post().body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `ByteArrayResource` in this case is not efficient, as the whole file content will be loaded in memory.

Using a `UrlResource` with the `"file:"` prefix or a `ClassPathResource` should solve both issues.

```
UrlResource resource = new UrlResource("file:///path/to/my/document.pdf");
```

Comment: That was only for the code sample here. In the actual code the resource already is a bytearray from a content repository. Not a file from the filesystem.