# Using Spring WebClient to upload a file in java

Tags: java, spring, upload, spring-webclient

I am trying to migrate from normal HttpPost methods to Spring WebClient and I have an API that accepts two files (one JSON and one PDF) for upload.

I am trying to send the files like below, but getting a 500 Internal Server Error instead of the 200 OK.

```
String jsonData ="";
ByteArrayOutputStream file;

MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
String header1 = String.format("form-data; name=%s; filename=%s", "attach", "file.pdf");
String header2 = String.format("form-data; name=%s; filename=%s", "jsonfile", "jsonfile.json");

// This line is causing the problem, Am I making a mistake here?
builder.part("attach", file.toByteArray()).header("Content-Disposition", header1);
// This line works fine.
builder.part("jsonfile", jsonData.getBytes()).header("Content-Disposition", header2);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("a url");

        byte[] fileContent = null;
        try {
            fileContent = webClient.post()
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, res -> handleError(res))
                .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
                .block();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
```

However, If I do not send the PDF file in the request, it works fine with only the JSON file.
With the Postman both cases work fine.

I assume that I am making a mistake when adding the PDF file to the request.
Though the file itself is a valid PDF, and the response of the API is a JSON file.

If someone could tell me what could possibly be wrong here.

Comment: There's an answer that covers fully reactive and non-blocking multi-part file upload in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665396

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After various changes, I was able to fix this issue. It might come handy for someone who stumbles into this issue.

Instead of using **file.toByteArray()** directly, use new **ByteArrayResource(file.toByteArray())** instead.

So the line looks like:

```
builder.part("attach", new ByteArrayResource(file.toByteArray())).header("Content-Disposition", header1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put "file.pdf" in line 5 into quotes solve your problem

Comment: The code that I shared, had all the used variables and constants replaced with strings for easier understanding.